# Combining Select AS statements; union not working

Tags: sql-server

I'm attempting a query and not succeeding.  The objective is to pull all manufacturer names and their corresponding URL types.  There is only one column for URLs (which can contain brochure, images and specs) and that is sTxtType, which is why I am using the like command.  I would like the data returned in a format like this...

nIdPub  Name  Brochure  Picture  Spec

The query below is pulling the correct data but the union is putting all data into one column under brochure like this...

nIdPub  Name  Brochure

See below please for query.  Thanks.

```
Use dbIdwWhseLC

Select tbItemTxt.nIdPub
,   sName
,   COUNT(sTxtType) As BROCHURE
From tbItemTxt 

Inner join tbMfrReporting 
On tbItemTxt.nIdPub = tbMfrReporting.nIdPub 
Where tbItemTxt.sTxtType like '%URBRO%'
Group by sName, tbItemTxt.nIdPub 

Union

Select tbItemTxt.nIdPub
,   sName
,   COUNT(sTxtType) As PICTURE
From tbItemTxt 

Inner join tbMfrReporting 
On tbItemTxt.nIdPub = tbMfrReporting.nIdPub 
Where tbItemTxt.sTxtType like '%URPIC%'
Group by sName, tbItemTxt.nIdPub

Union

Select tbItemTxt.nIdPub
,   sName
,   COUNT(sTxtType) As SPEC
From tbItemTxt 

Inner join tbMfrReporting 
On tbItemTxt.nIdPub = tbMfrReporting.nIdPub 
Where tbItemTxt.sTxtType like '%URSPE%'
Group by sName, tbItemTxt.nIdPub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this....

```
Select tbItemTxt.nIdPub
,   sName
,   COUNT(CASE WHEN tbItemTxt.sTxtType like '%URBRO%' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) As BROCHURE
,   COUNT(CASE WHEN tbItemTxt.sTxtType like '%URPIC%' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) As PICTURE
,   COUNT(CASE WHEN tbItemTxt.sTxtType like '%URSPE%' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) As SPEC
From tbItemTxt 
Inner join tbMfrReporting  On tbItemTxt.nIdPub = tbMfrReporting.nIdPub 
Group by sName, tbItemTxt.nIdPub
```

Comment: Thanks but the query is not returning any data.  The format of the columns is correct but no data populating in columns.  Any other ideas?

Comment: Please ignore last comment.  The local copy is down.  Thanks.

Comment: Accepted the answer.  Query executed perfect.  Thanks very much for the help.